CORS issue with RewritePath spring cloud gateway
I have three microservices with Micronaut and a Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Boot:

Assessment
Assessment-Bff
Course

I have configured the gateway using the YAML below:
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE
              - OPTIONS
              - HEAD
              - PATCH
              - TRACE
      routes:
        - id: course-service
          uri:
            ${COURSE_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8081}
          predicates:
            - Path=/course/**, /swagger/**
        - id: assessment-service-get
          uri: ${ASSESSMENT_BFF_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8083}
          predicates:
            - Path=/assessment/**
            - Method=GET
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/assessment/, /bff/assessment/

Each micro-service has enabled the CORS configuration as below
micronaut.server.cors=true

Without the RewritePath I am not face CORS. However when using RewritePath keep facing the CORS from the front end
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/assessment' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


I'm not familiar enough with Spring Cloud Gateway to know what's wrong with RewritePath, but be aware that listing TRACE as an allowed method in your CORS configuration is useless.

@jub0bs I have a requirement that if the method is GET it should redirect to different port in my case it is 8083. But for the PUT,DELETE and POST it should be 8082. So I need to filter by method

How is that related to TRACE?

@jub0bs Removing the TRACE is not working as well, I have put the updated section

I never claimed that removing TRACE would solve your problem; I only claimed that having it listed as an allowed method is useless.

The issue for me was I was missing OPTIONS on method
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:4200"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE
              - OPTIONS
              - HEAD
              - PATCH
      routes:
        - id: course-service
          uri:
            ${COURSE_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8081}
          predicates:
            - Path=/course/**, /swagger/**
        - id: assessment-service-get
          uri:
            ${COURSE_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8083}
          predicates:
            - Path=/assessment/**
            - Method=GET,OPTIONS <-- adding OPTIONS resolve the issue
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/assessment/?(?<segment>.*), /bff/assessment/$\{segment}
        - id: assessment-service-post-put-delete
          uri:
            ${COURSE_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path=/assessment/**
            - Method=POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS <-- adding OPTIONS resolve the issue

